# How do I access the request in Struts 2?

Tags: ajax, struts2

I am doing an AJAX post call to the action class on some action in the jsp page.

But I do not know how to access the request in my action class, or how to set the response for that request which will be sent back to the calling JSP.

Also I want to know whether i have to write code for that perticular action in a different way? That means what should be there in `struts.xml` for these types of actions.

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">; 
 <struts> 
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="populateDD" class="com.struts.action.FilterData"  
                method="populateDD">    
        <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
 </action> 
</package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 2):

Struts 2 does not care if a request is Ajax or not.

Whenever possible, you should *not* rely on servlet spec artifacts and instead use the default Struts 2 functionality of automatically mapping request parameters, and request attributes, to and from action properties.

For example, if you posted a "name" parameter via Ajax, and wanted to return something based on that, it'd look something like this:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String name; // Plus public getter and setter--from the request.
    private String someReturnValue; // Plus public getter and setter--for the view layer

    public String execute() {
        someReturnValue = "Your name is " + name;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

In the JSP you can access via the Struts 2 tags, or just use JSP EL:

```
<p>Return value is ${someReturnValue}</p>
```

If you *really* need access to the [request (FAQ)](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-can-we-access-the-httpservletrequest.html) or [response (FAQ)](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-can-we-access-the-httpservletresponse.html) (and you rarely do), you can.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 will work same way regardless you are going to call action using Ajax or normal for submit way.

Framework will take care of transferring the data to your action class and will do the type conversion for you so that you can concentrate on your business logic.

You need not to play around with Request Object as Struts2 will provide you the request parameters in a clean way.Framework has a build in mechanism called [interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/interceptors.html) which will do most of the work for you.

There is a interceptor named as `Param interceptor` will will take care of providing request data to your action class.

All you need to do take care of following things.

1. Place same name property in your action class which you are sending from your JSP with getter ans setter.

e.g
if you want to send few property from your JSP say

1. name.
2. age
3. sex

of your user, all you need to do is to declare these three property in your action class with there getter and setter, so you action class will look like

```
Public Class MyAction extends ActionSupport{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String sex;

  getter and setter for these properties

  public String execute() throw Exdeption{
       // Your business logic goes here
      // can use above properties
      return SUCCESS;

   }

}
```

Now when you will hit the submit button from your JSP page or send any Ajax request Framework will come in to action and see what all request parameters it have and to which action the request is going (based on `struts.xml`).It will check the action if it has same property name what you have defined in the jsp page if yes it will try to set there values by using the setter method of that property and if value need to be converted it will do the type conversion for you (Struts2 will do type conversion out of the box for some type).

So if you are sending `age` in the request it will look for a property namely `age` in your action class and than will try to set the value in the age property using its setter method.

When you have to send the value back to the `JSP/View`, all you need to do is to set the value in a property and provide its getter method.

Public Class MyAction extends ActionSupport{
      private String userName;

```
  getter and setter for these properties

  public String execute() throw Exdeption{
      userName="Sachin Kumar Rath";
      return SUCCESS;

   }

}
```

So in your JSP all you need to do is like

```
Hello ${Username}
```

So what happens is that when you use this `${Username}` Strust2 will use `OGNL(EL language)` and will call the `getUserName()` method in your action class to fetch the value of `userName` property.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks guys.
@Umesh
But I have one more query.
If I will send the request through AJAX then how to fetch the value of response in Client Side Ajax function.
Suppose I will set the response in some variable in ActionClass. Then how I will fetch the value of this variable.

Comment: when you using Ajax,even than your variable will be placed in the value stack and all you need is to access that using java-script.All i mean when response will be returned back from Action that variable will be the part of response.something like http://www.aoiblog.com/struts2-ajax-example/

Comment: I had set an variable like below in my action class.

setUserName="sachin";

Then in the ajax method I am doing the below stuff.

var res = ajaxRequest.responseText;
if (res){
alert(res.userName);
}

But it's not working.

Comment: @SachinKumarRath: a small googleing will help you how to parse ajax response ,can you show your struts.xml?

Comment: I know how to parse the response in Ajax function in the jsp part.
But here in my code I am not able to get the response that I had set in my Action Class.  

Below code is the content of my Struts.xml  
  

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
  
  <action name="populateDD" class="com.struts.action.FilterData"
   method="populateDD">
   <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
  </action>
  
    </package>
</struts>