# How use $.ajax() method in struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

Hello All i am using struts 2 and jquery plugin 1.8. Now i searche on google for using `$.ajax()` methos in struts. but i thoing i am not typing right keywords. Can any one give me tutorial how can we user this function with struts and handle response as String.

Comment: Are you asking about how they are interfaced (Java-JS-Java)?

Answer (score 3):

jquery is a javascript library and it can be included in struts just like any other framework, in the jsp page add the jquery

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

after that you can use it like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){ //document ready handler to ensure that the jquery is executed after the DOM is loaded

  //your code here
 $.ajax({
   url:'/your/path/',
   type:'POST',//by default is GET
   success:function(data){

    //success handler code
   },
   error:function(jxhr){
    console.log("o0ps!!");
   }

 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: thanks but how will i handle response. what result type i have to mention in `struts.xml`

Comment: may be this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595080/how-do-i-access-the-request-in-struts-2  i am not well versed in java frameworks

Comment: No, what you need is the struts2-json-plugin a number of questions here address using this plugin including struts.xml and annotations. Also the plugin documentation on the the org.apache.struts web site has good help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'ajaxAction?nodetitle='+title+'&filename='+fil,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data)
        {  
             console.log(stringify(data));                              
        }
 });
```

Explanation

1.Type is method type: Get or Post.

2.url is where you want to redirect here ajaxAction it is an action java file where you want to redirect. and after ? nodetitle and filename is two arguments send to action page.

3.dataType is: in which format you want your data back. here in json format.

4.Success Function: if Data Comes Back Successfully. then we use Stringify method to get data or you use System.out.println on
    server.