# stuts2 actions and jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How use $.ajax() method in struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474993/how-use-ajax-method-in-struts2)

simply,

**1**.can sombody tell me how to call a struts action through jquery ajax?(not struts jquery plugin)

**2**.and how can get results and how can send html output(result) to a target div correctly?

**3**.should we change the result types in struts configurations?

**4**.how to run javascript after ajax content have loaded?

**5**.and any other things i should  have known about struts actions regarding jquery ajax and javascript running.

please somebody can share a best reference for this or clean answer.

Comment: not explained..i need to know it correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can find bits and pieces of this information on the net easily. Let's put it at same page.

Ans 1::Include the js file of JQuery and  Write your ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",   //Default is GET
    cache : false, 
    data: sendingData,           //Data you need to send if in JSON format
    dataType: 'json',     //If json is required
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "MYACTIONNAME.action",          //URL you need to pass
    success: function(value) {
        alert(value.properties);        
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $(".errors").html("Please Try Again");
        //console.log(xhr.status + thrownError);
    }
});
```

});

That is for sending JSON and retrieving JSON from action class.
[Configuration of JSON can be found here along with other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12266588/1085285)

Ans 2::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#div").load("MYActionName.action"); //can do that through $.ajax also
});
```

If you want to show only part of the loaded HTML(converted JSP) , use

```
$("#divToReplaceWithNewOne").hide().load('MyActionName.action #newDivWhichWillbeFilled').fadeIn(1000);  //with animation
```

Ans 3:: It all depends on what you want . You have to configure if you want pdf or other thing.

a) Whole JSP

```
<action name="MYActionName" class="MYActionNameBean" method ="execute">
            <result name="success" type="dispatcher">
                <param name="location">/jsp/MyNewPage.jsp</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

b) Working with streams and setting content through ActionClass only

```
<action name="MYActionName" class="MYActionNameBean"    method="execute">
            <result type="stream">
                    <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
                    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Method::

```
public String execution() throws Exception {
        try{
            PrintWriter outWriter = null;
            StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer("");
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
            try {
                outWriter = httpResponse.getWriter();
                                        sbf.append("String to be sent to View");
                    }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{

                if(outWriter!=null){
                    httpResponse.setContentType("text/html");
                    outWriter.println(sbf.toString());
                    outWriter.flush();
                    outWriter.close();
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyOwnException(e);
        }
        return null;
        }
```

c) With JSON as result. (struts2-json plugin)

```
<action name="MYActionName" class="MYActionNameBean"    method="execute">
            <result type="json"></result>   
        </action>
```

d) PDF

```
<action name="DownloadPdf" class="PrintPdfActionBean" method="executeViewPdf">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
                <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment; filename="${fileName}.pdf"</param>  //filename is variable in action class
                <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Ans::4.   Thats all JQuery In success/done/deferred callbacks you can put your js
Example snippet::

```
success: function(value) {
            var respStat = data.status; 
                var errorStat = data.errorsMessages;
                if(respStat =="success"){
                    responseMsg.removeClass().addClass('successMessage').html("Your changes have been saved successfully.").fadeOut(4000);
                    }
                else{
                    responseMsg.removeClass().addClass('errorMessage').html(errorStat[0]).show();
                }
},
```

Comment: thanks Ashish.but one thing. should i place my onload js inside the success function?

Comment: its better to do that. so that you can show error in case of any other issues to the user.